# C# - NHibernate unable to cast NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet to System.Collections.Generic.IList

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

For some reason, NHibernate is telling me it can't convert `NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet[Ingredient]` to `System.Collection.Generic.IList[Ingredient]`, when I try to get the data from the database. This is a simplfied version of my class mapping/implementation:

```
public class Product {
    protected Product() { };

    public virtual Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Ingredient> {
        get { return new List<Ingredient>(ingredients).AsReadOnly(); }
        protected set { ingredients = value; }
    }

    private IList<Ingredient> ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();
}
```

--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="LanchesAdmin.Core.Domain.Product, LanchesAdmin.Core" table="product" >
        <id name="ID" generator="identity">
            <column name="id" not-null="true" />
        </id>

        <property name="Name" column="name" length="64" not-null="true" />

        <set name="Ingredients" table="ingredient" fetch="join" lazy="true" inverse="true">
            <key column="product_id" />
            <one-to-many class="LanchesAdmin.Core.Domain.Ingredient, LanchesAdmin.Core" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I've seen several related questions, but they all tell me to use IList, and that's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: try removing creation of new list and the ReadOnly call.

Comment: @Euphoric, tried it, didn't really make any difference.

Comment: @Raphael_ could you post your code that eventually worked. And if possible, could you post the code for `Ingredient` (or explain what it is). I am running into a problem and am wondering whether your solution will fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @REMESQ here's the whole project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgfha79lr6yz6cy/LanchesAdmin.rar

Mappings and Implementations should be should be on `LanchesAdmin.Core/Domain`. PS: It's pretty amateur code, but I hope it'll shed you some light.

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that you are using a set. And `PersistentGenericSet<T>` simply doesn't implement the `IList<T>` interface.

I think you should simply make the property of type `IEnumerable<Ingredient>`.
This solves two problems:

1. You get rid of the error you mentioned
2. The API of your class directly communicates that consumers of your class aren't allowed to add ingredients via that property.

Comment: I've made it work with ICollection, is IEnumerable any better?

Comment: @Raphael_: Yes, `ICollection<T>` still looks like the user can add items via this property. `IEnumerable<T>` on the contrary is a read only interface. That's what you clearly want.

Comment: I'd like to be able to add/remove items to this collection from inside my class, through a public method.

Comment: That's ok. You can still leave the *field* as an `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a list, bag or set? Your domain model contains a `IList<T>` but you've mapped it as a `<set>`.

Either change your mapping to a `<bag>` or `<list>` or change your domain model to use a `ISet<T>`.

Comment: Could you review your answer? I think you missed some words.

Answer (score 1):

Either change type of the property to `ISet` from `IList`.

Or change mapping from `<set>` to `<list>`.